# alert number above letter T

Tags: css

I have an alert field that I want to show the number of messages.

I want to place the num div like this:

[image]

above on the right of the image.

how can I do this?

```
 #num{
 font-size:10px;
 min-width:10px;
 text-align: center;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:0px;
}

T<span id=num>0</span>
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x6sehmyo/

thank you!

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, please select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`<sup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) - `HTML Superscript Element`

```css
sup {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
T <sup>0</sup>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<br><br>

T<span id=num>0</span>
```

**CSS**

```
 #num{
 font-size:10px;
 min-width:10px;
 text-align: center;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:0px;
 position:relative;
 top:-10px;
}
```

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/x6sehmyo/2/

You may have to adjust the `top` property to fit your needs

Comment: But if you want more control over the element, this would be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`<sup>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup).

```html
<p>
  T<sup class="msg-count">0</sup>
</p>
```

```css
.msg-count {
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4fyyk8s/)